# Benchmark MySQL on SSD: Tools and Strategies

Tags: mysql, sql, database, linux

I'm currently switching my servers from running MyISAM on hard drives to InnoDB on SSD.

I have a **3,800,000 rows (16GB)** table as the benchmark table.

My server set up:

- Ubuntu 64 + Nginx + MySQL 5.5 + ...

I have two things in mind that I would to test very much:

- how the switch from hard drives to SSD would affect concurrency
- how the switch from MyISAM to InnoDB would affect concurrency

I have questions regarding both the tools and the strategies:

- since I'm mostly interested in concurrency, **what tools should I use to do the test?** I've played with **Siege** and I found it really easy to play with. But I think there should be plenty of even more powerful linux softwares that better suit my needs.
- **what do the testing strategies look like?** I understand that the choice of strategy may have a tight relationship with the tool that I choose to use. For example, when playing with Siege, I need to write a PHP script that performs some heavy-lift MySQL operations, upload it to server, pass the script URL as a parameter to Siege (which is installed in my local laptop) and let Siege simulate the concurrent traffic for me.

Comment: 16GB/ 380K rows:: you have an average rowsize of > 32K. Maybe you should redesign your data model?

Comment: @wildplasser Sorry it should be 3,800,000. I just updated my question. Thanks for pointing that out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic tests are ok, but only real load will tell You the difference between software & hardware configuration. Maybe try to:

1. Dump database from production server
2. Capture all queries from production server (use slow query log to that, set long_query_time = 0)
3. Load database into test configuration and play slow query log on it (use pt-log-player).
4. Again capture all queries from test server with long_query_time = 0.
5. Analyze results from slow query log with pt-query-digest.

I reference here tools from [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/) for MySQL (although some tools might need Percona Server, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 2):

An important thing to remember when benchmarking MySQL storage performance in Linux is cache.  I was curious about the same test case myself.  It's always funny when a user complains about a slow query.  They call you and run again only to find their 50+ minute query now completes in 30 seconds because of query cache.  Always run a

```
mysql> reset query cache;
```

in MySQL when trying to optimize queries.  That said, there's one more step when comparing SSD to traditional spindles:  disk cache.  It's difficult to compare access times or IOps when the OS is caching disk in memory on its own.  To clear disk cache, run the following from a shell:

```
$ sync && sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

These commands run before each of your benchmark queries will help you realize the potential of your SSD compared to that 7k2 SATA slowpoke you have.  Verify this by running the same query twice without flushing cache and observing query times.  At this point, it's a good idea to try some queries with and without indexes, as well as some joins if possible.  Use EXPLAIN PLAN on each query to verify that an index is used.  The random access of reading between index and data files will expose bottlenecks on slower disks.  Make sure your my.cnf is consistent between your SSD benchmarks and your platter.  I tested some things on a simple desktop OCZ SSD and noticed query performance gains around 10x as fast as my 7200rpm SATA disk.  In an SSD-based transactional database, I would be careful when using OPTIMIZE TABLE as frequent database compaction combined with SSD TRIM may affect disk life.  That's theoretical though, and I have yet to see evidence to support this.

Hope this helps!  I can't wait for the days when magnetic HDs replace tape as backup medium and find themselves completely replaced by SSD in most hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The type and quality of the SSD makes a big difference. Don't use a desktop SATA SSD for mysql if you have a busy server. You won't get the performance boost you think you will.

There are some great articles here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/search/innodb+log+file+ssd/